# ms-access: doing repetitive processes with vba/sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, service

i have an access database backend that contains three tables. i have distributed the front end to several users. this is a very simple database with minimal functionality. i need to import certain rows from a file every hour into one of the tables in the database. i would like to know what is the best way to automate this process so that i can have it running hourly. i need it to be running sort of as a service in the background. can you tell me how you would do this?

Comment: what OS do the users use?  cron jobs work great in Unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have for example:

- a ms-access file with all necessary code to run the import proc
- a BAT file containing the command line(s) that will run this ms-access file with all requested parameters. Check ms-access command line parameters to see the available options.
- a task scheduler service software to launch the BAT file: depending on the task scheduler and the command line to be sent, you could even avoid the BAT file step

Comment: Well the complete syntax might be 'application.quit'. Please check it in MS Access Help

Comment: The correct syntax for the 'quit' line in an MDB file is: DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll

Comment: Why do I always forget these DoCmd things? But my proposal was correct: "The Quit method quits Microsoft Access. You can select one of several options for saving a database object  before quitting. Syntax: expression.Quit(Option), where 'expression' is a variable that represents an Application object."

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is run some queries, I would not do this by automating all of Access, but instead by writing a VBScript that uses DAO to execute the SQL directly. That's a much more efficient way to do it, and will run without a console logon (which may or may not be required for full Access to be run by the task scheduler).

Comment: will it need full Access if i also need to do an RunImportorExport thing

Comment: To use TransferText/TransferDatabase, you'd need full Access. But you can use SQL instead with IN clauses with connect strings specifying the data source and destination, and it will work with just DAO/Jet. You might have to fiddle around a bit with the connect strings (I usually create a linked table and then copy that to the SQL statement).